# Conversion from mpf_t to char* str in GMP

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gmp

I have some value stored in `mpf_t res` and trying to copy it to `char* my_res`. I found this `mpf_get_str` function in [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Floats.html), and tried the code below:

```
char* my_res;
mpf_t res;

// give res some value

mpf_get_str(my_res, NULL, 10, 230000, res);
```

And this raised me the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. I haven't used C++ for some time, could someone give me a brief recap? Thanks.

Comment: You're writing to a random address since you don't assign `my_res`. Try creating a buffer first. `char buf[x];`

Comment: `char buffer[sizeof(mpf_t)*230002];` shouldn't have worked? I get the same error.

Comment: You should include the whole code of using the buffer. Also, quickly reading through the documentation I found that the buffer **should point to a block of n_digits + 2 bytes**. In your case, its `230000 + 2` which is `230002` not `sizeof(mpf_t) * 230002`.

Comment: If you are doing C++, you should really use one of the existing C++ wrappers for GMP. There is one that comes with GMP, in gmpxx.h, type mpf_class, from which you can easily get a std::string.